# how to hash user input into unique id

Tags: hash

I want to create an unique and short id(it could allow the collision) with users input(such as 'today is beautiful!' and etc.)
but I find the MD5 is too long(32 bits) so there are any other methods for me to solve this problem.

Comment: MD5 produces a 128 bit hash value.

Comment: @Mihai 32-bit hexadecimal system.. My mistake!

Comment: Bits are always in binary system. You are probably referring to digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose whatever hashing algorithm you like and trim it to the length you need.

E.g.: last 6 digits of the MD5.

Comment: If you like the solution and it solves your problem, you should also accept it.